# How to call meteor helpers with dynamic params within a template

Tags: events, meteor, helper

i have the following template :

```
<template name="tempName" >
  {{#each helperOne "1" "2" }}

    <p>Lorem upsom</p>
  {{#each}}
  <a id="next"></a>
</template>
```

the helper :

```
template.tempName.helpers({
    "helperOne":function(a,b)
     {
       console.log("a  = "+a+"   b ="+b); 
     }

});
```

i want to define a click on a DOM to set dynamically the params to helpers defined with the values  "1" and "2" on the template tempName

```
    template.tempName.events({
   "click .next":function(e,tmp)
     {
       //how change dynamically a and b of the helperOne helper into the 
       // template defintion of tempName
     }

    });
```

thank you for help

Comment: hey @bouraoui {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values. You cannot pass params to a {{#each}} block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ReactiveVar`s like this :

JS

```
Template.tempName.onCreated(function(){
  this.arg1 = new ReactiveVar("1");
  this.arg2 = new ReactiveVar("2");
});

Template.tempName.helpers({
  helperOne: function(arg1, arg2){
    console.log("helperOne called with", arg1, arg2);
  },
  arg1: function(){
    return Template.instance().arg1.get();
  },
  arg2: function(){
    return Template.instance().arg2.get();
  }
});

Template.tempName.events({
  "click .next": function(event, template){
    template.arg1.set("whatever");
    template.arg2.set("you want");
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="tempName" >
  {{#each helperOne arg1 arg2}}
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  {{#each}}
  <a class="next"></a>
</template>
```

Don't forget to add the package to your Meteor app.

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

Comment: @benstr i try it ,the code run well and i resolve the problem :)